# How to unit test code that includes a database transaction

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, tdd, moq

How to put unit around the below codes:

```
public DbContextTransaction QTTransactionBegin()
    {
        return Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

public int CreateCampaign(CreateCampaignModel createCampaignModel)
    {
        using (var transaction = _qtContext.QTTransactionBegin())
        {
            try
            {
                var campaign = new Campaign();
                campaign.CampaignCode = createCampaignModel.CampaignCode;
                campaign.CampaignDescription = createCampaignModel.CampaignDescription;
                campaign.CampaignDate = createCampaignModel.CampaignDate;
                campaign.CampaignNotes = createCampaignModel.CampaignNotes;
                campaign.OwnerUserID = createCampaignModel.OwnerUserID;
                campaign.AddedOn = DateTime.Now;
                campaign.AddedBy = createCampaignModel.OwnerUserName;
                campaign.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                campaign.UpdatedBy = createCampaignModel.OwnerUserName;
                campaign.CampaignSegments = GetCampaignSegmentList(createCampaignModel);

                var campaignId = AddOrUpdateCampaign(campaign);
                transaction.Commit();
                return campaignId;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Could anyone advise me how to put unit test around above code ?

I tried the code as below :

```
Database_database;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _qtDALMock = _factory.CreateMock<IQTDAL>();
        _campaignRepository = new CampaignRepository(_qtDALMock.MockObject);
    }
 [TestMethod]
    public void Check_CreateCampaign_Test()
    {
        // arrange 
        const int expectedCampaignId = 1;
        var createCampaign = QueryToolDummies.CreateCampaignModel;

        _database.BeginTransaction();
        _qtDALMock.Expects.One.MethodWith(x => x.QTTransactionBegin())
            .WillReturn(_database.BeginTransaction());
        _qtDALMock.Expects.One.Method(x => x.AddOrUpdateCampaign(null))
            .With(Is.TypeOf<Campaign>())
            .WillReturn(expectedCampaignId);

        // act
        var result = _campaignRepository.CreateCampaign(createCampaign);

        // assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

this `_database.BeginTransaction()` has a problem. the error says can't use like it.

Please advise.

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue, it's quite tricky to work around.

I tried creating a wrapper class for the context that exposes a `BeginTransaction()` method, but ultimately you end up needing to mock the `DbContextTransaction` returned by `BeginTransaction()` when it comes to testing, but `DbContextTransaction` has neither an interface or a public constructor.

In the end I wrote a transaction manager class that creates and manages its own transaction and exposes methods for beginning, committing and rolling back the transaction.  That manager class, and the service that returns it, can then be faked allowing the code using transactions to be fully tested.

I've written that up fully [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059665/1879019).

Answer (score -1):

One question? Why are you trying to start a transaction into a unit test?

Will be easy if you Mock your repository using `Moq framework` and return what you need to return from the repo.

In fact, I thought that start a `BeginTransaction()` in a unit test is not a good practice.

I hope this helps

Comment: I am testing code from repository layer. so I couldn't mock repository layer. could you please explain why transaction in unit test is not a good pratice ?

Comment: I meant that not to use BeginTransaction. Use this one using (var ts = new TransactionScope()), using TransactionScope, if you don´t use Complete method, the transaction will not be completed. If you use BeginTransaction, you will need to call Rollback to don´t perform the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to unit test more than one unit.

Assuming that the code above is your 'data layer' / repository then you are performing an integration test because more than a single unit is involved in the test.

You could include setup / teardown for the database within your test class and call the SUT (subject under test) with valid and invalid data to validate expected behaviours.